# Regex Match substring in middle of string

Tags: c#, regex

I need help completing a regex expression. I have the following regex: /(?i)encntr(?-i)/gi

https://regex101.com/r/t4pUkr/1/

I have the following three filenames:

- 20200207050000-20200207162558-encntr.txt - should match using encntr
- 20200207050000-20200207162558-encntrprov.txt - should NOT match using encntr
- 20200207050000-20200207162558-encntrlocation.txt - should NOT match using encntr

My above regex matches all 3 but I only want it to match the first bullet point.<s>So I'm trying to use the ^(not) operator to achieve this but I'm not getting anywhere.</s> Ignore the previous sentence, my understanding using ^ was ill-informed. Additionally it would be more robust if I could do this without depending on the - and . that encntr, encntrprov, and encntrlocation are wrapped in. I do not author the files and can't guarantee the author follows a naming convention. Thus I cannot not guarantee the - and . will always be there.

Example of possible other file names:

- 20200207050000-20200207162558encntr.txt - should match using encntr
- 20200207050000-20200207162558encntr01.txt - should match using encntr
- 20200207050000-20200207162558_encntr_.txt - should match using encntr
- 20200207050000-20200207162558^encntr^.txt - should match using encntr
- 20200207050000-20200207162558FinalencntrUploaded.txt - should match using encntr

The point of using this regex is to remove the inner if statement from my code. I am iterating over enum values and checking if the enum value is present in the incoming filename.

Right now the code uses txtFilename.Contains(possibleIdentifierLower, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) to see if the incoming filename contains one of enum values. But in the case of enum encntr, the Contains method returns true for encntr, encntrprov, and the encntrlocation filename. So I have to do an additional check to figure out which one it is. I want to leverage the regex to match only to encntr, encntrprov, or encntrlocation by supplying those values in the regex. Thus encntr couldn't not match to encntrprov or encntrlocation using the regex.

Here's the code snippet I'm trying to update.

```
public static FilenameIdentifierEnum IdentifyFile(string txtFilename)
{
    FilenameIdentifierEnum identifier = FilenameIdentifierEnum.unassigned;

    foreach (FilenameIdentifierEnum possibleIdentifier in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FilenameIdentifierEnum)))
    {
        // I would like this Regex.Match to eliminate the need to have the inner if statements 
        //if(Regex.IsMatch(txtFilename, $"(?i){possibleIdentifier.ToString()}(?-i)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        if (txtFilename.Contains(possibleIdentifierLower, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            identifier = possibleIdentifier;

            if (identifier == FilenameIdentifierEnum.encntr)
                identifier = EncntrCaseChecking(txtFilename, identifier);
            if (identifier == FilenameIdentifierEnum.appt)
                identifier = ApptCaseChecking(txtFilename, identifier);

            break;
        }
    }

    if (identifier == FilenameIdentifierEnum.unassigned)
    {
        throw new UnknownFileException($"Unknown identifier in filename or no file identifier in filename found. Text Filename: {txtFilename}");
    }

    return identifier;
}

private static FilenameIdentifierEnum EncntrCaseChecking(string txtFilename, FilenameIdentifierEnum possibleIdentifier)
{
    possibleIdentifier = (txtFilename.Contains(FilenameIdentifierEnum.encntrloc.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        ? FilenameIdentifierEnum.encntrloc
        : possibleIdentifier);

    possibleIdentifier = (txtFilename.Contains(FilenameIdentifierEnum.encntrprov.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        ? FilenameIdentifierEnum.encntrprov
        : possibleIdentifier);

    return possibleIdentifier;
}

private static FilenameIdentifierEnum ApptCaseChecking(string txtFilenameLower, FilenameIdentifierEnum possibleIdentifier)
{
    return (txtFilenameLower.Contains(FilenameIdentifierEnum.apptpart.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
         ? FilenameIdentifierEnum.apptpart
         : possibleIdentifier);
}

public enum FilenameIdentifierEnum
{
    unassigned,
    encntr,
    encntrprov,
    encntrloc,
    persondemo,
    personbenefitcoverage,
    personprov,
    medication,
    immunization,
    allergy,
    diagnosis,
    problem,
    labresults,
    socialhistory,
    vitals,
    procedures,
    appt,
    apptpart,
    appointments,
    appointmentparticipant,
    encounterlocation,
    result
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `/(?i)encntr\.txt$/`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements. Please try to explain why it should only match the first one and what do you mean by the "not operator"? Are you looking for [`encntr(?!prov|location)`](https://regex101.com/r/pUy4c3/1)?

Comment: Should there be a match from the second examples as well? If you want to match the filename, and want to make use of the `^` not in a character class, try using lookarounds (if supported) `(?<![^\W_])(?i)encntr(?-i)(?![^\W_])` https://regex101.com/r/kXN7cz/1 else use a capturing group `(?:\W|_)(?i)(encntr)(?-i)(?:\W|_)` https://regex101.com/r/dokDMX/1

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I edited the question hopefully that clears it up for you.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, bullet points 4-7 should match. Only bullet points 2 and 3 shouldn't when using "encntr." Bullet point 2 should be the only match when using encntrprov. Similarly bullet point 3 should be the only match when using encntrloc.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, hopefully this edit is better and acceptable.

Comment: @DuxClarus Yes, it's much better now and I voted to reopen the question. I would say Regex is probably not the right choice here. You should keep using `String.Contains()` but you should check for "encntrprov" and "encntrloc" before you check for "encntr". To do that dynamically, I would iterate the enum values (like you did) but after putting them in a descending order based on their length. That way, you can be sure that the smaller strings (e.g., "encntr") get checked last.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AhmedAbdelhameed and thank you for helping me form a better question. It's been a while since I posted on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
(encntr\..*?)
```

Matches with substring `encntr.` only.

Note that `^` is not a (not) operator.
`^` is for matching from beginning of a string.

Comment: Are you sure? I found this off regex101 "[^a-z]
Matches any characters except those in the range a-z."

Comment: @DuxClarus `^` has a completely different meaning (which you just described) when used with a character class `[^]`. So, `^a` would match the letter `a` only when it's at the beginning of the string. While `[^a]` would match any character except the letter `a`. As to your question above, it's still not clear and you talked about your code but didn't mention what programming language you're using. Please edit the question, include the appropriate tag for the language you're using and describe what you're trying to achieve with examples (not just the regex part of the problem).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thank you for the clarification on the ^ character. I didn't know depending on how it was used it had  different meanings.